# How to boot 18.04 using external monitor on Lenovo z50 70?

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, external-monitor

At startup I now must use my laptop screen for startup; immediately after logging in, I can close the lid and use the external monitor. How can I power up and login only using the external monitor? (I used to open the laptop just for turning it in.)

Answer (score 0):

In the Display configuration dialog, select your laptop monitor and set it to "Off".

In the Power Management dialog choose 'Do Nothing' for "When laptop lid is closed."

This is how I do it in MATE. Your desktop may use different terms but this procedure should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stephen. I think it's not working, because I have preinstalled gnome with ubuntu 18.04.. It took me a while founding out why have you called me a MATE. You see I'm totally noob to linux.

Comment: ...eventhough 1 comma was missing.